# swift get black screen when swipe

Tags: swift

In main vc (in main storyboard i have navigation controller and view controller) after load all setting (from server) i present new vc

```
DispatchQueue.main.async {
  var stor: UIStoryboard!
  stor = UIStoryboard(name: "Profile", bundle: nil)
  let viewcontroller = stor.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "profileVC")
  let nav = UINavigationController(rootViewController: viewcontroller)
  self.present(nav, animated: true, completion: nil)   
}
```

in `profileVC`

```
navigationController?.interactivePopGestureRecognizer!.delegate = self // enable swipe to back

// present new vc
var stor: UIStoryboard!
stor = UIStoryboard(name: "Settings", bundle: nil)
let viewcontroller = stor.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "settingsVC")
self.navigationController?.pushViewController(viewcontroller, animated: true)
```

but sometimes i get black screen [image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tpchw.jpg) (in `profileVC`) and [image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IiuCP.png) (in another vc pushed from `profileVC`) when swipe the screen

How can i fix it ?

Answer (score 0):

Remove the `UINavigationController` from the `profileVC` and present only the view controller. If you want to explicitly add navigation controller use `show(_ vc: UIViewController, sender: Any?)` instead

Edit:
Probably the flow that you are looking for is the following:

`UINavigationController` -> `MainViewController` -> *show* `ProfileViewController`

How to add the navigation controller:

- go to the storyboard (assuming you are using one)
- select the view controller (Main)
- Editor -> Embed In -> Navigation controller

PS: Do not force unwrap (`navigationController?.interactivePopGestureRecognizer!.delegate = self`) properties that you don't have control over (and preferably ever)

Comment: u mean in `main vc` instead `self.present(nav, animated: true, completion: nil)` do `self.show(viewcontroller, sender: self)` ?

Comment: `present` shows the view controller ( navigation controller in your case ) modally
You should remove the navigation controller `let nav = UINavigationController(rootViewController: viewcontroller)` and directly `show` the detailed view controller, that way you will have the swipe action for free
(You will have to add navigation controller to the MainViewController)

Answer (score 0):

I guess you have clear the colour the of your superview.Double check it.It happens when you clear the colour of your superview.